ADFS Domain-Local Group Cliams are not Passing Through
We created group membership ADFS claim rule with global security groups. And its working smoothly, but we need to add users from different forest which trusted with us. So, converted global group to Domain local group so that we can add user from different forest but somehow its not working, only Global group is working not Domain local, even if user is from same domain.
Can someone help me to get the proper solution or Domain Local group not supported by ADFS if we used for claim attributes.ADFS Version 4
